# Stop a running process in a Linux terminal through the Python subprocess module (airodump-ng)

Tags: python, aircrack-ng

I wrote a program (I ran it in the terminal) that goes through a list of terminal commands ([Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux)).

```
import subprocess as sub
import time
sub.call(['airmon-ng', 'start', 'wlan0'])
p = sub.call(['airodump-ng','wlan0mon'])
time.sleep(10)
p.kill()
```

The last commmand is `airodump-ng wlan0mon`. Everything works fine (everything is displayed in the terminal (beacons, essid, etc.).

After a specified time I wish to kill the process (`airodump-ng wlan0mon`).

I don't want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> by hand!
`p.kill()` does not work (maybe improper use).

How can I do this? What command should I send through the subprocess module?

Comment: all of this is to automate the task a bit. the program iterates through other commands also. `ifconfig wlan0 down' etc. the code works. i just wish to terminate it.

Comment: related: [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess.call` method is a **high-level API** that **waits for the process to terminate** before returning its exit code. If you need your main process to continue running while the subprocess runs, you need to use the slightly lower-level API: `subprocess.Popen`, which starts the process in the background.

Using `p = sub.Popen(['airodump-ng','wlan0mon'])` instead of `p = sub.call(['airodump-ng','wlan0mon'])` should work.

Comment: now it does. thank you